# Please help! Not able to read from a USB multimeter

Tags: python, usb

I am still quite new to USB protocol, and I need help extracting data from a digital multimeter using a USB connection and Python on my Raspberry Pi. Here I have a very basic Python script for reading from a generic USB device, and note that the idVendor and idProduct variables are correct for the multimeter I am using:

```
import usb.core

dev=usb.core.find(idVendor=0x067b,idProduct=0x2303)
ep=dev[0].interfaces()[0].endpoints()[0]
i=dev[0].interfaces()[0].bInterfaceNumber
dev.reset()

if dev.is_kernal_driver_active(i):
dev.detach_kernal_driver(i)

dev.set_configuration()
eaddr=ep.bEndpointAddress

r=dev.read(eaddr,1024)
print(len(r))
```

When I try to execute the script while the multimeter is reading a voltage, I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usbRead.py", line 6, in <module>
    dev.reset()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 949, in reset
    self._ctx.managed_open()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 131, in managed_open
    self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 804, in open_device
    return _DeviceHandle(dev)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 652, in __init__
    _check(_lib.libusb_open(self.devid, byref(self.handle)))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 604, in _check
    raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue
```

My apologies if this is an amateur question, but I've been trying my best to solve the insufficient permissions problem, but every solution I could find is filled with jargon that I'm hopeless in understanding. There was one thread that discussed changing things in a "rule file", and when I tried that, I ended up completely bricking the Raspberry Pi I was using!

Please help a novice like me on how I can be able to get data from this USB multimeter. Thank you so much in advance! I can answer questions for additional information as best I can.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USBError: \[Errno 13\] Access denied (insufficient permissions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625363/usberror-errno-13-access-denied-insufficient-permissions)

Comment: I've seen that before. The problem is that I have absolutely zero clue how rules or rules files work, embarrasing! I would greatly appreciate if someone can help walk me through that.

Comment: are you on a iMac? either way , do you have a usb rules file in this path... /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usbftdi.rules ? (i.e. open terminal app and paste that file path in terminal prompt, see if that file exists)

Comment: Using the terminal, I found that file does not exist. Also I am using a Raspberry Pi for this project, so I am working with Linux.

Comment: try creating that file. there's many helpful resources on the topic: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=279731, https://www.sparkfun.com/news/2332, etc

Comment: Thanks for your help, the insufficient permissions has been solved, but now I have a new timeout error. I posted this as a separate question if you're also willing to help me with that. Thank you!