# Windows 10 - USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)

Tags: python, windows, error-handling, camera, usb

I'm trying to access Logitech Meetup cam over usb, with python 3.11.4:

```
import usb.core

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x046D, idProduct=0x0866)

dev.set_configuration(0)
```

and getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\usb\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    dev.set_configuration(0)
  File "C:\usb\venv\Lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 915, in set_configuration
    self._ctx.managed_set_configuration(self, configuration)
  File "C:\usb\venv\Lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\usb\venv\Lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 158, in managed_set_configuration
    self.managed_open()
  File "C:\usb\venv\Lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\usb\venv\Lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 131, in managed_open
    self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\usb\venv\Lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 804, in open_device
    return _DeviceHandle(dev)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\usb\venv\Lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 652, in __init__
    _check(_lib.libusb_open(self.devid, byref(self.handle)))
  File "C:\usb\venv\Lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 604, in _check
    raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

This error was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625363/usberror-errno-13-access-denied-insufficient-permissions), but it's related to linux.

I've installed pyusb, libusb, "Filter Wizard" (libusb-win32 filter), don't remember where I've seen this suggestion, checked that the folder has permissions for admin... nothing helps :(